# Is it wrong to use templates with the implicit assumption that certain member functions of the parameterized type will be defined?

Tags: c++, templates, members

Say you write a really bad class

```
template <typename T>
class IntFoo
{
  T container ;
public:
  void add( int val )
  {
    // made an assumption that
    // T will have a method ".push_front".
    container.push_front( val ) ;
  }
} ;
```

Ignore the fact that the class assumes the container will be `something<int>`, instead pay attention to the fact that

```
IntFoo< list<int> > listfoo ;
listfoo.add( 500 ) ; // works

IntFoo< vector<int> > intfoo;
//intfoo.add( 500 ) ; // breaks, _but only if this method is called_..
```

In general, *is it ok to call a member function of a parameterized type like this*?  Is this bad design? Does this (anti)pattern have a name?

Comment: The name is called template method pattern or have i mistaken it?

Comment: @ahenderson: You are mistaken. Confusingly, the _Template Method Pattern_ has nothing to do with templates.

Comment: It's one way of dealing with the fact that a method cannot be virtual and template at the same time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is perfectly fine and called compile-time duck typing and employed at all kinds of places all over the standard library itself. And seriously, how would you do anything useful with a template without assuming the template argument to support certain functionalities?

Let's take a look at *any* algorithm in the stdlib, e.g., `std::copy`:

```
template<class InIt, class OutIt>
OutIt copy(InIt first, Init last, OutIt out){
  for(; first != last; ++first)
    *out++ = *first;
  return out;
}
```

Here, an object of type `InIt` is assumed to support `operator*()` (for indirection) and `operator++()` for advancing the iterator. For an object of type `OutIt`, it's assumed to support `operator*()` aswell, and `operator++(int)`. A general assumption is also that whatever is returned from `*out++` is assignable (aka convertible) from whatever `*first` yields. Another assumption would be that both `InIt` and `OutIt` are copy constructible.

Another place this is used is in any standard container. In C++11, when you use `std::vector<T>`, `T` needs to be copy constructible *if and only if* you use any member function that requires a copy.

All of this makes it possible for user-defined types to be treated the same as a built-in type, i.e., they're fist-class citizens of the language. Let's take a look at some algorithms again, namely ones that take a callback that is to be applied on a range:

```
template<class InIt, class UnaryFunction>
InIt for_each(InIt first, InIt last, UnaryFunction f){
  for(; first != last; ++first)
    f(*first);
  return first;
}
```

`InIt` is assumed to support the same operations again as in the `copy` example above. However, now we also have `UnaryFunction`. Objects of this type are assumed to support the post-fix function call notation, specifically with *one argument* (unary). Further is assumed that this the parameter of this function call is convertible from whatever `*first` yields.

The typical example for the usage of this algorithm is with a plain function:

```
void print(int i){ std::cout << i << " "; }

int main(){
  std::vector<int> v(5); // 5 ints
  for(unsigned i=0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    v[i] = i;
  std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), print); // prints '0 1 2 3 4 '
}
```

However, you can also use *function objects* for this - a user-defined type that overloads `operator()`:

```
template<class T>
struct generate_from{
  generate_from(T first) : _acc(first) {}
  T _acc;
  void operator()(T& val){ val = _acc++; }
};

int main(){
  std::vector<int> v(5); // 5 ints
  // yes, there is std::iota. shush, you.
  std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), generate_from<int>(0)); // fills 'v' with [0..4]
  std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), print); // prints '0 1 2 3 4 '
}
```

As you can see, my user-defined type `generate_from` can be treated exactly like a function, it can be called *as if it was a function*. Note that I make several assumptions on `T` in `generate_from`, namely it needs to be:

- copy-constructible (in the ctor)
- post-incrementable (in the `operator()`)
- copy-assignable (in the `operator()`)

Comment: This begs to mention the failed first attempt to introduce concepts.

Comment: So where do you _document_ your expectations for T? For example, in a comment? `// T SHOULD BE A POINTER TYPE`, `// T SHOULD SUPPORT T->getAverage()`,

Comment: @bobobobo: Normally through the parameter name. `template<class RanIt>` documents that `Iter` should support random-access iterator operations. Other than that, documentation. See the standard with all the predicates the algorithms take. In the documentation they only say what operations `Pred` should support.